How to create a Google Maps list using Python API
There is an option on Google Maps to create a list of places that can be shared with other users. For example: Food map of Amsterdam. Is there a way to do it using Google Maps python api? I see that there is an option to create a static map and this way I can add markers and store a map as an image.
import googlemaps
from googlemaps.maps import StaticMapMarker

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY')


m1 = StaticMapMarker(
    locations=[(62.107733, -145.541936)], color="blue", label="S"
)

m2 = StaticMapMarker(
    locations=["Delta+Junction,AK"], size="tiny", color="green"
)

m3 = StaticMapMarker(
    locations=["Tok,AK"], size="mid", color="0xFFFF00", label="C"
)

response = gmaps.static_map(
    size=(400, 400),
    zoom=6,
    center=(63.259591, -144.667969),
    maptype="hybrid",
    format="png",
    scale=2,
    visible=["Tok,AK"],
    markers=[m1, m2, m3],
)
f = open('result.png', 'wb')
for chunk in response:
    if chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
f.close()

But how do I create it the way that it can be displayed in Google Maps and shared using a url?

That Food map of Amsterdam was created using Google My Maps (you can tell because the URL is google.com/maps/d/viewer and not under googleapis.com).
Searching for "api" in the My Maps Help shows a few results, none of which mention any API. This is because My Maps is meant to be used by people directly, rather than 3P applications, so there is no API for it.
